# Are question about genealogy companies on topic?

Tags: discussion

Questions about genealogy products are generally on topic. But what about question regarding genealogy companies? For example:

- Is Ancestry.com affiliated with the LDS church?
- When will Random Acts of Genealogy Kindness be back online?

Comment: My initial vote is no, but I can't articulate why.

Comment: Are you aware that Random Acts was the project of an individual person (now deceased) not a company? In that case, would "Is there interest in establishing a new home for RAoGK or a similar service?" be an acceptable question?

Comment: @Fortiter Yes, I was using the word "company" quite liberally.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Exchange sites have been known to provide community and technical support for 3rd-party products. But your second second example (outage reports and resolution) involves **customer services issues better suited to *their* sites.**

Stack Exchange works really well when we are *one* of the available options to support a product's community, but that synergy doesn't typically include specific customer support issues (i.e. no feature requests, bug reports, billing issues, product road maps, future directions, etc).

Answer (score 2):

I actually don't have a problem with the questions, especially the examples you gave. Where I do think we will be challenged is in making sure the ANSWERS are referenced.*

*Then again, I think we are already being challenged because there are posted answers that should and easily could have contained references. This includes that several accepted answers don't include any references.

Question: Is there a way to recommend this particular question (and what we learn from the discussion) be part of the town hall?

Answer (score 0):

I think factual answer to the example questions you give would be OK, plus (for example) details of the record coverage for a particular company or organisation; I don't think comparisons or recommendations would be appropriate.